# Changing the value of multiple switches in a UITableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiswitch

I have a tableview with UISwitch in each row of the table. Switch is set as accessory view of the cell.When I change the value of the switch in the first row, the other switches should also change to the same value as my first switch. Currently on the switch value changed event, I am checking if value changed switch is the switch in the first row. But then how can I access/change values of switches in the other cells/rows.

Comment: can you show the code for adding the switches ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store values of switches somewhere and set it in `cellForRow` method. So simply in your model set this values to 1 and call `tableView reloadData`.